# How can I save a checkbox state in a Wordpress custom meta box?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have written the following code, but it won't save the state. The checkbox always reverts to being checked:

```
<?php

/*META BOXES*/ 
function add_film_meta_boxes() {
add_meta_box('film_meta_data', 'Film info:', 'film_meta_box_callback', 'film', 'advanced', 'high');
}

function film_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field('save_film_meta_data', 'spanish_meta_box_nonce');
$spanish = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_spanish_value_key', true);

echo '<label>Subtitles: </label>'; 
$spanish_subtitle_field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'spanish_subtitle_field', true);
if($spanish_subtitle_field == "yes") {$spanish_subtitle_checked = 'checked="checked"';} else {$spanish_subtitle_checked = '';}

echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="spanish_subtitle_field" name="spanish_subtitle_field" value="yes" '.$spanish_subtitle_checked.' /></label><label for="spanish_subtitle_field" style="font-weight:normal !important;">spanish &nbsp;</label>';
}

function save_film_meta_data ($post_id) {
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return;
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )) 
    return;
if( ! isset($_POST['spanish_meta_box_nonce']) ) 
    return;
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['spanish_meta_box_nonce'], 'save_film_meta_data') ) 
    return;
if ( ! isset( $_POST['spanish_subtitle_field'])) 
    return;
$spanish = isset($_POST['spanish_subtitle_field']) ? 'on' : 'off';
update_post_meta($post_id, '_spanish_value_key', $spanish);
} 
?>
```

The code is included in my functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong, this make your metabox have a value 'on' or 'off'.

```
$spanish = isset($_POST['spanish_subtitle_field']) ? 'on' : 'off';
```

And when you check if is checked, you looking for a 'yes' value.

```
if($spanish_subtitle_field == "yes") {$spanish_subtitle_checked = 'checked="checked"';} else {$spanish_subtitle_checked = '';}
```

So try this new function and check if works:

```
function save_film_meta_data($post_id){
  if(! isset($_POST['spanish_meta_box_nonce'])){
    return;
  }
  if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['spanish_meta_box_nonce'],'save_film_meta_data')){
    return;
  }
  if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
    return;
  }
  if(! current_user_can('edit_post',$post_id)){
    return;
  }
  if( ! isset($_POST['spanish_subtitle_field'])){
    return;
  }
  $my_data = isset($_POST['spanish_subtitle_field']) ? $_POST['spanish_subtitle_field'] : 'no';
  update_post_meta($post_id,'_spanish_value_key',$my_data);

}
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested but the checkbox still always reverts to the checked state :(

Comment: Try echo the get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_spanish_value_key', true), if return some value the function is saving the value, if not is something worng.